# If $\gcd (x,4) = 2$ and $\gcd(y,4) = 2$ then $\gcd(x+y,4) = 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I was working my way through some number theoretic proofs and being a newbie am stuck on this problem :

> *If $(x, 4) = 2$ and $(y, 4) =2$, then $(x + y, 4) = 4$,* 
>    where $(a,b)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

**My Solution  (Incorrect)**

- $x-4 = 2t$
- $y-4 = 2p$
- $x + y - 8 = 2(t+p) \Rightarrow x + y - 4 = 2f + 4 = 2(f+2)\Rightarrow 2$ divides $(x+y , 4)$

**My Question:**

My solution is definitely inadequate. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$x$ has to be one of the forms $:4t,4t+1,4t+2,4t+3$ where $t$ is some integer

As $(x,4)=2,x=4t+2$

Comment: Hi , @labbhattacharjee , but is x not only divisible by 2 . That means x mod 2 = 0 or 1 i.e. x is of the form 2t or 2t+1 . Why is x of the form 4t , 4t+1 etc. ?

Comment: @pranav, As we have $(x,4)=2$

Comment: (x,4) = 2 means that the gcd of x & 4 is 2 . I do not think it implies that x is divisible by 4 . Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: @pranav, Is $x=4t+2$ divisible by $2$ or by $4?$

Comment: by 2 . But why do you say that x is of the form 4t , 4t+1  ,etc.

Comment: @pranav, $x$ is either $2u,2u+1$ But $(2u+1,4)=1$ So, $x=2u\implies(2u,4)=2\implies2(u,2)=2\iff(u,2)=1\implies u$ must be odd $=2v+1$(say)

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me , @labbhattacharjee ,  and providing a sublime explanation . Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20331/discussion-between-pranav-and-lab-bhattacharjee).

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x=2a$ and $y=2b$, with odd $a$ and $b$. Thus
$$
x+y=2(a+b)
$$
and $a+b$ is even. Thus $x+y$ is divisible by $4$.